# How can i write a ruby program to implement a text editor?

Tags: ruby

How to write a ruby program to implement a text editor which can be run in the  terminal itself.In the text editor the operation to be performed is

## colorcode :"Some text"

then the text should be displayed in that color...

Comment: Your question is about a whole project. It is way too vast to ask as a question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it would take more than a couple lines of code :p

But if you're concerned about changing text colors inside the shell, I'd start with the Curses implementation in the standard library:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html

Comment: It will be good idea t show a small code for the same.. :)

Comment: can u give me an out line on how to get it done?